# How can "as" modify a List; type promotion using as, is, ! operator

Tags: dart

**Minimal reproducible code**

```dart
void main() {
  dynamic list = [1];
  var foo = list as List<int>; // Commenting this line makes below line to cause error. 
  var bar = list.map<int>((e) => e);
}
```

Error:

> type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(int) => int' of 'f'

In doing `list as List<int>` I believe I'm not modifying `list` in any way. But it seems like the `list` is indeed modified. Can anyone tell me why there's a "Magic"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Dart 2.12, `as` (and similarly, the null assertion operator (`!`)) can cause type promotion for local variables.

It's the same thing that allows:

```dart
void main() {
  dynamic list = [1];
  if (list is List<int>) {
    var bar = list.map<int>((e) => e);
  }
}
```

to not generate any static type errors.  By using `list as List<int>` instead, you are essentially asserting that `list` is a `List<int>`: if `list` is not actually a `List<int>`, the cast would fail at runtime and an exception would be thrown.  Therefore the type system can statically deduce that `list` is a `List<int>` for all reachable code after the cast.

Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36883#issuecomment-812729193.

Comment: Maybe add that this only works because `list` in this example actually points to a `List<int>` object since `[1]` creates a `List<int>` object. So `list is List<int>` is working since `list` is actully a `List<int>` object (check with `runtimeType`). If we instead creates the list with `<dynamic>[1]` we can no longer cast the list using `list is List<int>` or `list as List<int>`.

Comment: @julemand101 I've updated my answer to try to be clearer. "Works" in this context means that it passes static analysis, not necessarily that it won't throw an exception at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You are right: the list is not actually being changed, but the Dart type system regards the types of list and foo differently. While the elements of list are of type dynamic since no type annotation is provided, the elements of foo are explicitly cast to `int` by using the `as` keyword.

You can find more information about this behavior in the official Dart language guide: https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#dont-use-a-dynamic-list-as-a-typed-list